# Upload and display image in Javaweb

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

My Simple Website is using Spring MVC. The user uploads product images and thewebsite will display the image (with product name , price, etc..). The database only store the details of the image, and I store the image in a directory. The problem is, I am not sure where the  image store should be.

```
// Creating the directory to store file
            File dir = new File(imageDirectory);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + name);
```

For example, when the value of variable imageDirectory is "\temp", my application will store the image in "D:\temp" and i don know how to get the image url to show on my website

when the value of variable imageDirectory is "temp", my application store the image in "D:\soft\sts-bundle\sts-3.5.1.RELEASE\temp" and i dont know how to get the image url to show on my website

So where i should store upload image in and how do I get the uploaded image url (stored in the database) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show your image to the end user, you must store it relative to your web app.

The ideal approach for it will be to have a dedicated folder in your webapp for storing uplaods and then sending the relative url to that folder to the end user.

E.g.

```
  //request is an instance of HttpServletRequest

  File uploadDirectory = new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/uploads"));

  if (!uploadDirectory.exists()) {
      uploadDirectory.mkdirs();
  }

  File reportFile = new File(reportDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);

  String requestUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
  requestUrl = requestUrl.substring(0, requestUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "uploads/" + fileName;
  return requestUrl;
```